# Can google charts treemap customize the borders of boxes?

Tags: css, google-visualization, treemap

I know this is very trivial but there is nothing in the documentation. I am using google charts treemap for monitoring something. If all the parent level rectangles are green, the distinct boxes aren't much clear because they are just divided by very thin white line. Can we customize the borders of each rectangle, like black line or increasing the width among each rectangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide your own css, just keep in mind the chart is svg.
To change the border color, something like this should work.

```
rect {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

See following example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Location', 'Parent', 'Market trade volume (size)', 'Market increase/decrease (color)'],
      ['Global',    null,                 0,                               0],
      ['America',   'Global',             0,                               0],
      ['Europe',    'Global',             0,                               0],
      ['Asia',      'Global',             0,                               0],
      ['Australia', 'Global',             0,                               0],
      ['Africa',    'Global',             0,                               0],
      ['Brazil',    'America',            11,                              10],
      ['USA',       'America',            52,                              31],
      ['Mexico',    'America',            24,                              12],
      ['Canada',    'America',            16,                              -23],
      ['France',    'Europe',             42,                              -11],
      ['Germany',   'Europe',             31,                              -2],
      ['Sweden',    'Europe',             22,                              -13],
      ['Italy',     'Europe',             17,                              4],
      ['UK',        'Europe',             21,                              -5],
      ['China',     'Asia',               36,                              4],
      ['Japan',     'Asia',               20,                              -12],
      ['India',     'Asia',               40,                              63],
      ['Laos',      'Asia',               4,                               34],
      ['Mongolia',  'Asia',               1,                               -5],
      ['Israel',    'Asia',               12,                              24],
      ['Iran',      'Asia',               18,                              13],
      ['Pakistan',  'Asia',               11,                              -52],
      ['Egypt',     'Africa',             21,                              0],
      ['S. Africa', 'Africa',             30,                              43],
      ['Sudan',     'Africa',             12,                              2],
      ['Congo',     'Africa',             10,                              12],
      ['Zaire',     'Africa',             8,                               10]
    ]);

    new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('chart_div')).draw(data, {
      minColor: '#f00',
      midColor: '#ddd',
      maxColor: '#0d0',
      headerHeight: 15,
      fontColor: 'black',
      showScale: true
    });
  },
  packages:['treemap']
});
```

```css
rect {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Neat! Thanks WhiteHat